# Looking at current desktop through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, remote-access

Is there any way for me to look at the current running desktop through ssh? Meaning, if I ssh from machine A to machine B, I get terminal access in machine B. And if I run ssh -X from A to B, I can launch GUI programs. 
But is there any way for me to see the desktop as it appears on machine B? I have some processes running on machine B, and it isn't an option to kill them and start them again via ssh. (One of the processes is a GUI application, but the rest are running through terminal.)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11623/13792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It's called [Virtual Network Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). You need to run a VNC server of your choice on the host machine(B), and you will need a client on your local machine(A).

There should be more options on both VNC server/clients but [TigerVNC](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tigervnc/index.php?title=Welcome_to_TigerVNC) is an open source free option.